# Disallowed Host error when trying to deploy me serverless app with Zappa

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've followed [the tutorial for deploying zappa](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/zappa-or-how-to-go-serverless-with-django/#crayon-5b25827866812126721523) step-by-step. When it says to `Add the returned URL to the ALLOWED_HOSTS` I have done that (as well as add the development server):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'https://*******.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev']
```

However I still get this error:

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '********.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'. 
You may need to add '********.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

Comment: Add the host, not the URL.

Comment: Would that be `amazonaws.com`? @KlausD.

Comment: Luckily the error message tells you exactly what to add.

Comment: `You may need to add '********.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'` - I've already tried that (omitting `/dev`) to the URL but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `https://` and `/dev` is what solved the problem. So your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` should look like this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '*******.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com']
```